# spring cloud configuration vs local properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-properties

I have a spring boot application with `application.yaml`, also I gonna switch a `Spring Cloud Config Server` on.

The question is: which properties of these 2 above have a priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Spring application can use a **Config Server** as a property source.

Properties from a Config Server will override those defined locally *(e.g. via an `application.yml` in the classpath)*.